# How to give Java run time more heap space?

Tags: windows-7, jre, out-of-memory

I am running PMD v4.2.5 on Windows 7 and it is running out of memory with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I configure the JRE to allow the process to consume more memory?  I have 4 GB of RAM and would hope that is enough.

Comment: I don't know the correct answer, but I heard that 64bit JRE in some cases fixes the problem, so try it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch 'java' with `-Xmx<memory>` option. e.g.

```
java -Xmx512m ...
```

Use `java -help` to display options. The `-Xmx` option is a non-standard option. Use `java -X` to display a list of non-standard options.

Answer (score 4):

If calling from the commandline add `-Xmxnnnm` to the commandline to set the max to nnn mb.  Ex: `-Xmx256m` to give the heap 256 mb of memory.